# Moving a Laravel 4 project to a new machine

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am moving to a new machine so I zipped my Laravel project and added it to the new machine.  I forgot to copy my database information though and I don't currently have access to it.  I created a fresh database and tried to run `php artisan migrate` but it fails because it is trying to do an insert on one of the tables from the database I was using the project with on the old machine.  I can't use composer or access the site in browser either.  What do I need to do to get things running properly on this machine?

Comment: just manually create the table that is missing?

Comment: That would make the migrations pointless.  I don't want to have to go to all the work of creating all the schema for the tables manually when I should be able to just run it.

Comment: yes - but you have obviously missed a table somewhere in your migration, that was manually created on your old server. Just create a new migration for that table?

Comment: No, I have all the old migrations in my project still.  I think the problem is in some cached file or something that Laravel generates somewhere because I get the same error if I try to do anything with artisan or composer.  Why would composer care if I am missing a table when I try `composer update`?

Comment: @vikingsfan19 Composer cares because executing Laravel's scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a database on the current machine, you will get the error. It will complain that it can not find the database or table. If you set up database locally, you don't have to set up database again.